# Signture the message with private key and TouchID or FaceID swift

Tags: ios, swift, rsa, signature, touch-id

I have created a private key in the Keychain with `SecKeyCreateRandomKey`.  When I attempt to access the key to perform a signing operation, the Touch ID or FaceID dialog will never appear. I get the sign string but without TouchID or FaceID. I tried with `BiometryAny` and `TouchIdAny` but it doesn't work.

```
static func createKey(keyName:String){
    DispatchQueue.main.async{
    var error : Unmanaged<CFError>?
    print("Key is generating for \(keyName)")
    let tag = (keyName + "PrivateKey").data(using: .utf8)!
    // private key parameters
    var privateKeyParams: [String: Any] = [:]
    let accessControlError:UnsafeMutablePointer<Unmanaged<CFError>?>? = nil
    // ^ Already a 'pointer'
    if #available(iOS 10 , *) {
        let allocator:CFAllocator!         = kCFAllocatorDefault
        let protection:AnyObject!             = kSecAttrAccessibleWhenUnlockedThisDeviceOnly

        let flags:SecAccessControlCreateFlags = SecAccessControlCreateFlags.userPresence
        let accessControlRef = SecAccessControlCreateWithFlags(
            allocator,
            protection,
            flags,
            accessControlError // <- Notice the lack of '&'
        )
        privateKeyParams = [
            kSecAttrIsPermanent as String: true,
            kSecAttrApplicationTag as String: tag,
            kSecAttrAccessControl as String : accessControlRef!,
        ]
    } else {

        // Fallback on earlier versions
    }


    // global parameters for our key generation
    let parameters: [String: Any] = [
        kSecAttrKeyType as String: kSecAttrKeyTypeRSA,
        kSecAttrKeySizeInBits as String: 2048,

        kSecPrivateKeyAttrs as String: privateKeyParams
    ]
     if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
        do{
            guard let privateKey = SecKeyCreateRandomKey(parameters as CFDictionary, nil) else {
                print("\(keyName)PrivateKey generator Error!")
                throw error!.takeRetainedValue() as Error
            }
          }
       }
    }
```

and signture function:

```
static func SigntureWithPrivateKey(keyName: String, message : String) -> String {
    //print("sign started .........")
    guard let messageData = message.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8) else {
            print("bad message to sign")
            return ""
    }
    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
        guard let privateKeyLocal: SecKey = getPrivateKey("\(keyName)PrivateKey") else
        {
            return ""
        }
        guard let signData = SecKeyCreateSignature(privateKeyLocal,SecKeyAlgorithm.rsaSignatureDigestPKCS1v15SHA512,messageData as CFData, nil) else {
            print("priv ECC error signing")
            return ""
        }
        let convertedSignData = signData as Data
        let convertedString = convertedSignData.base64EncodedString()
        return convertedString

    } else {
        return ""
    }


}
```

and getPrivateKey function :

```
fileprivate static func getPrivateKey(_ name: String) -> SecKey?
{
    let query: [String: Any] = [
        kSecClass as String: kSecClassKey,
        kSecAttrKeyType as String: kSecAttrKeyTypeRSA,
        kSecAttrApplicationTag as String: name,
        kSecReturnRef as String: true
    ]

    var item: CFTypeRef? = nil
    let status = SecItemCopyMatching(query as CFDictionary, &item)

    guard status == errSecSuccess else
    {
        if status == errSecUserCanceled
        {
            print("\tError: Accessing private key failed: The user cancelled (%@).", "\(status)")
        }
        else if status == errSecDuplicateItem
        {
            print("\tError: The specified item already exists in the keychain (%@).", "\(status)")
        }
        else if status == errSecItemNotFound
        {
            print("\tError: The specified item could not be found in the keychain (%@).", "\(status)")
        }
        else if status == errSecInvalidItemRef
        {
            print("\tError: The specified item is no longer valid. It may have been deleted from the keychain (%@).", "\(status)")
        }
        else
        {
            print("\tError: Accessing private key failed (%@).", "\(status)")
        }
        return nil
    }

    return (item as! SecKey)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry your question is quite long so I thought I would give generic answer.

- Make sure you have set **NSFaceIDUsageDescription** in your
  info.plist

  Without this key, the system won’t allow your app to use Face ID. The
  value for  this key is a string that the system presents to the user
  the first time your  app attempts to use Face ID. The string should
  clearly explain why your app  needs access to this authentication
  mechanism. The system doesn’t require a  comparable usage description
  for Touch ID.
- Make sure you have added both Security and LocalAuthentication
  framework other than turning on keychain services
- You have to specifically set Authentication param in
  SecAccessControlCreateWithFlags class(Please go through this clearly it makes lots of difference)

Please find more information along with sample source code here

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/localauthentication/accessing_keychain_items_with_face_id_or_touch_id

Hope this helps.

Comment: i have NSFaceIDUsageDescription in my info.plist and i have to set Authentication param in SecAccessControlCreateWithFlags, but doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Do not use the simulator, try it on a real device.

Comment: I use real device

Answer (score 0):

you need to set flag as

```
let flags:SecAccessControlCreateFlags = 
 [SecAccessControlCreateFlags.privateKeyUsage, SecAccessControlCreateFlags.touchIDCurrentSet]
```